# failed to load org.mariabd.jdbc.Driver

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I have a Spring app that runs fine from the IDE with local mariadb using the mariadb 2.7.4 in the POM as below but I get the error second below running it on Ubuntu.  I have removed the mysql connector and still the problem.  Any help to why the discrepancy and soution?

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
... 173 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:223)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:175)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:85)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
... 174 more

Answer (score 1):

I needed to explicity include the driver in the war.  In the IDE it was implicitlly included.  Sorry for the trivial answer that should have been pre-discovered.